# python string format: how can I combine width and dictionary elements using str.format()

Tags: python

I am trying to format a dictionary and specify elements' width using the newer str.format():

```
>>> record = { 'name': 'Donald Trump', 'age': 12 }
>>> print "{name} {age}".format(**record)
Donald Trump 12
>>> # how would I set width for the name field to accommodate longer names
```

How do I use a combination of dictionary attributes access *and* formatting like width control?

Comment: You are asking for 3 elements. One is "silent" before the `:`. Simply change to: `print "{name:>30} {age}".format(**record)`

Comment: Thats the answer but sagism can't accept a comment :)

Comment: Read this [pyformat summary](https://pyformat.info/) which has a lot of different formatting options and helpful explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax:

```py
In [31]: print("{name} {age}".format(**record))                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Donald Trump 12

In [32]: print("{name:>30} {age}".format(**record))                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                  Donald Trump 12

In [33]: print("{name:30} {age}".format(**record))                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Donald Trump                   12
```

Notice that I am using Python 3.7, you should remove the parenthesis from the `print` method if you're using Python<3 (which I do not recommend).

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> align           ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"

```py
>>> '{:<30}'.format('left aligned')
'left aligned                  '
>>> '{:>30}'.format('right aligned')
'                 right aligned'
>>> '{:^30}'.format('centered')
'           centered
```